# Why am I getting a blocked script execution error?

Tags: javascript, csscritic

I am using http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/ to turn html into a canvas. When I change the code to:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("save_image_canvas");
// rasterizeHTML.drawHTML('<div style="font-size: 20px;">Some <span style="color: green">HTML</span> with an image</div>', canvas);
rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(document.getElementById("mattes").innerHTML, canvas);
```

I get the following error in the console:

> Blocked script execution in 'Mysite/Custom_App/' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

All the scripts and content are located on the same server.

Here is the full function:

```
function common_screenshot()
{
  var canvas = document.getElementById("save_image_canvas");
  if (typeof(moulding_canvas) === "undefined")
  {
    canvas.height = parseInt($("#matte_canvas").height());
    canvas.width = parseInt($("#matte_canvas").width());
  }
  else
  {
    canvas.height = parseInt($("#moulding_canvas").height());
    canvas.width = parseInt($("#moulding_canvas").width());
  }
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";

  var moulding_top = -1 * parseInt(document.getElementById("moulding_canvas").style.top);
  var moulding_left = -1 * parseInt(document.getElementById("moulding_canvas").style.left);

  console.log("top: " + moulding_top);
  rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(document.getElementById("mattes").innerHTML).then(function (renderResult) 
  {
    context.drawImage(renderResult.image, moulding_left, moulding_top);
  });
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(matte_canvas, moulding_left, moulding_top);
  if (typeof(moulding_canvas) !== "undefined")
  {
    ctx.drawImage(moulding_canvas, 0, 0);
  }
  var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  return image;
}
```

The image that results from the rasterizeHTML is fine when it is on the screen, but when I call `canvas.toDataURL`, the image that results is all black.

Comment: by same server, you also mean same port and not using file:// ? What matters is the [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), not the server

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Read the link I gave : "server" is too ambiguous here to know if you do things right.

Comment: I think I am doing things right. I'm not sure. The commented line works without the error

Comment: Also affects CSScritic. So i added the tag.

Comment: Just a side note for others - Adblock chrome extension can also cause this error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Judging by the error message, you are using a Webkit-based browser, most likely Chrome. This error message (introduced [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104365)) is displayed when an `<iframe>` element with [`sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) is attempting to run JavaScript (only allowed when `allow-scripts` is specified in that attribute). A look at the rasterizeHTML source code shows that the function [createHiddenSandboxedIFrame()](https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js/blob/351ef70b3634b6a8b1ce331abd8e9418231dd292/dist/rasterizeHTML.js#L363) creates such a frame. It is used for `calculateDocumentContentSize()`, the contents of the document are being copied into the temporary sandboxed frame in order to measure their size. Apparently, that document also contains some `<script>` tags and these cause the error (not because of the script origin but because scripts are generally disallowed).

Now your code doesn't call `calculateDocumentContentSize()` of course. It is being called by function `drawDocumentImage()` called by function `doDraw()` called by function `rasterizeHTML.drawDocument()` called by function `rasterizeHTML.drawHTML()`. In the end, the issue is really: the HTML code you are passing in contains `<script>` tags.

Given that executing scripts on the HTML code you are drawing doesn't seem to be the intention (no `executeJS` option), you should be able to simply move the `<script>` tags somewhere else, so that they aren't inside the `mattes` element. If that's impossible, you can still run some a regular expression on the source code to remove all script tags, something like:

```
var code = document.getElementById("mattes").innerHTML;
code = code.replace(/<\/?script\b.*?>/g, "");
rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(code, canvas);
```

**Edit**: Inline event handlers like `ondrop` attribute will also trigger that warning of course. You can remove these as well:

```
code = code.replace(/ on\w+=".*?"/g, "");
```

Note that this will only help you get rid of the warning. I doubt that this warning is what is causing the image to be blank - so you probably need to ask one more question on that.

Comment: When I output document.getElementById("mattes").innerHTML, I get `<div id="opening_0" style="background-color: #bfbfbf; position: absolute; left: 45px; top: 45px; height: 202.5px; width: 157.5px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 6;" ondrop="drag_drop_drop(event, this)" ondragover="drag_drop_allow_drop(event)" onclick="photos_add_selected_fid(this);">&nbsp;</div><canvas id="matte_canvas" width="247" height="292" style="z-index: 3; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></canvas>` I see no script tags.

Comment: I also tried using that code and I still get the error.

Comment: @AllisonC: ondrop attribute and similar also contain JavaScript code.

Comment: So what would I need to do. I can't remove those in the original code.

Comment: That removes the error but it when it actually saves the image, the contents of that div are all black

Comment: @AllisonC: As I said in the edit already, you mixed together two questions here. You were asking about the error, I answered that. Why your image isn't produced correctly is an entirely different question and there isn't enough information here to answer it.

Comment: You're right. I created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510571/when-calling-canvas-todataurl-why-is-the-part-from-rasterizehtml-drawhtml-black

Comment: Looks like that second regex has an unescaped space:
should be `code.replace(/\ on\w+=".*?"/g, "");`

I'd submit an edit, but SO only allows edits longer than six characters

Comment: @Orangetronic: No, escaping the space is unnecessary, but if you do it I recommend using `\s` anyway. This regular expression isn't meant to be a proper solution however, it should be safer to either accept the warning or to remove the attributes from DOM before drawing.

Comment: @WladimirPalant, interesting — I was getting errors if I didn't escape the space… but I'm using coffeescript in this case, which is a bit special.

I didn't actually have any `<script>` tags or event handlers in the DOM I was trying to render, but I did have SVG, which seems to also cause the same warning. In safari, it seems to prevent exporting all together…

Comment: @Orangetronic: Yes, that's CoffeeScript enforcing a special syntax, not JavaScript.

Comment: @WladimirPalant the more you know! thanks for clarifying .

Answer (score 3):

@WladimirPalant has a good description. If you experience this on a site that you do not control you can start Chrome with the command below and Chrome will accept the scripts.

Windows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --allow-scripts
```

Linux:

```
google-chrome --args --allow-scripts
```

Comment: @Ciberman Were all Chrome processes shut down before you tried this? Chrome needs to boot from scratch otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Yes. I solved adding "allow-scripts" atribute in my script tag.